# Discord API: reading all messages from a channel

Tags: discord, bots

I'm trying to interact with the Discord API, created an application, and trying to use the following endpoint:
https://discord.com/api/channels/843835119579562035/messages?limit=50
However I get an error: 401, unauthorised. I am authenticated and have a proper access token, in fact, I'm able to use this endpoint: https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds
My user is added to the server of that channel.
My endgoal is to be able to monitor a channel and be notified of new messages in that channel, without actually adding a bot to the server. Is that even possible?
Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to create a python script who listens the messages on a discord channel that I have access to (guest access I am not admin of the guild).
I would like the script to detect some specific messages so I can do a sort of "web scraping" on that discord channel.
I obtained a token using my secret key. But I can only use [oauth/@me](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#get-current-authorization-information) api endpoint.
Everything else I try gives me 401 unauthorised response.

Comment: If I use this header in my API requests: 
```
headers = {
    'authorization': f"Bot my_bot_token"
}
```
It works for more API endpoints. However that requires to get my bot invited in another guild and that is not possible.
I can't use a bot user for that. I want an app that pretends it's me.

Comment: "Self-botting", which is automating normal user accounts to perform actions is explicitly **not allowed** by Discord and can result in account termination. See https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-